# Nesting if statements inside a While loop?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ a couple of weeks ago, so i'm far from an expert. I have a small project due in a couple of hours and I've came across a problem. I tried nesting two if statements inside a while loop, but it seems to be only running the first one and completely disregards the second one. Here's the code:

```
while (x <= rows * columns) {
    cout << "*";
    x++;
    if (x % intervals == 0) {
        cout << "?";
        x++;
    }
    if (x % columns == 0) {
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
cout <<"\nDONE!!!";
```

It doesn't run the second if statement, therefore I can't get any line breaks (rows).

Comment: It _does_ "run the second if statement". C++ does not randomly skip statements. Check your logic. Particularly that `x++` .... Write out your algorithm on paper and step through it iteration by iteration.

Comment: The x++ is the suspect here. The program is certainly executing the if statement. It's likely the condition is not satisfied

Comment: You could debug your code, or add `cout << x;` prior to each `if` statement.

Comment: `It doesn't run the second if statement,`  The `if` statement is run.  What isn't run are the statements within the `if` block, since `x % columns` is never 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you cannot have two or more if statements in a while loop.

without the context it is hard to say what is going wrong.

however, as you are running x++ within one of the IF statements you could potentially be causing the loop to exit before you hit your "column" condition as you could be skipping the value of "X" that is divisible by your Columns ( stated in x % columns)

Please provide some context

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this: 
I merely factorized the `x++` line.

```
while (x <= rows * columns) {
    cout << "*";
    if (x % intervals == 0) {
        cout << "?";

    }
    if (x % columns == 0) {
        cout << "\n";
    }
    x++;
}
cout <<"\nDONE!!!";
```

Answer (score 0):

If columns is a multiple of intervals, the second statement will never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Found My problem. The reason it was skipping it was because the trial I was running was with an odd number and the x was initialized as 1. So the second x++ in the first if statement was making the x skip through that odd number. Therefore x % columns never resulted in 0. I fixed it though. Thanks anyways guys.