# loops missing the nested if

Tags: c++, nested-loops

My loop is skipping the nested 3rd `else if`. What should I do so it does not skip it?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int loop, i;
    loop = 0;    

    char choice, selection;

    std::cout << "Welcome" << std::endl;
    while (loop == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Please a choice" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "a. Run" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> selection;
        if (selection == 'a')
        {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "run" << std::endl;

                std::cout << "do you want to continue running? (y/n)";
                std::cin >> choice;
                if (i < 5 && choice == 'y')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (i < 5 && choice == 'n')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if ( i > 5 && choice == 'y')
                {
                    std::cout << "Limit Reached"; 
                }
            }
        }
```

I want it to print `"limit reached"` when `i > 5`, but somehow the loop skips it. What am I doing wrong?

Previous StackOverflow questions did not help much. I tried their solutions, but they did not solve my issue.

**Edit**:

For example: [Nesting if statements inside a While loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464533/) I have looked if I have initialized any of my `int` which might be messing my loop.

Looks like my `else if` didn't work because the condition I gave it would never be true. I feel stupid. But thanks everyone for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your loop is `for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)`.  Will `i` ever be grater than `5` in the loop?

Comment: The first thing to do is [learn how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). That will help you solve this problem, and many more you will have in the future.  Any time you “tried their solutions, but they did not solve my issue” you need to tell us what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. Otherwise people will assume you will also ignore whatever they tell you.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver, Now I feel stupid.  Why didn't I noticed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop runs only while `i` is in the range `1..4` inclusive, so `i < 5` will *always* be true and `i > 5` will *never* be true.

You should check the value of `i` after the loop exits.  You should also check the user's input to make sure it matches your expectations.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

bool shouldContinue(const char *prompt)
{
    char choice;

    do
    {
        std::cout << prompt << " (y/n)";
        if (!(std::cin >> choice)) throw ...;
        if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y' || choice == 'n' || choice == 'N') break;
        std::cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    return (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
}

int main()
{
    bool loop = true;
    int i;
    char selection;

    std::cout << "Welcome" << std::endl;

    while (loop)
    {
        std::cout << "Please a choice" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "a. Run" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> selection;

        if (selection == 'a')
        {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                std::cout << "run" << std::endl;

                if (!shouldContinue("do you want to continue running?"))
                    break;
            }

            if (i == 5)
                std::cout << "Limit Reached"; 
        }       

        ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```